# visual studio find dialog grows

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I remember seeing a blog post about how to fix the Visual Studio 2010 bug where the Find dialog grows in width every time you bring it up, but I didn't get around to following it, and now I don't remember where I saw it.  Anybody have a link to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a link to the patch to install

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/29/patch-for-vs-2010-find-and-replace-dialog-growing.aspx

Comment: If you don't mine me asking, how did you find it?  Is your google-fu better than mine?

Comment: i have an RSS feed of this blog and i had to apply the patch last week so i knew exactly where it was - just lucked out with it i guess

Comment: You can also read through the Connect list of hotfixes for visual studio: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads